# Can I see actual App installs instead of new users in Google analytics App Properties?

Tags: google-analytics

Google's documentation refers to [install tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3389142?hl=en) for mobile apps when they only provide new users in acquistion reports. To me there is a difference between newly acquired users and the total number of app installations at any point in time. Is there a way to track actual app installations? Do I have to refer to Google Developer Console and iTunes connect? And if so, should new users match installs in those tools for the same period?